# Why does casting a type T& to T create a temporary?

Tags: c++, casting, reference

In Effective STL item 22 Meyers appears to imply that casting a `T&` to a `T` instantiates a temporary; that is

```
T x;
T& y = x;
((T)(y)).doSomething();
```

results in `doSomething()` being done on a temporary rather than `x`.

Why must the cast result in a temporary?

Comment: Because you're creating a new object. It's (kind of) the same as `T tmp = y; tmp.doSomething()`. `T(y)` is a new object which is a copy of `y`, and only exists for the entire full expression (until the `;`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why must the cast result in a temporary?

According to the standard, `(T)(y)` *constructs a temporary value* of type `T`.

The behavior of the explicit type conversion using the cast notation is described in the C++11 Standard as follows:

> **5.4 Explicit type conversion (cast notation)**
>
> 1 The result of the expression `(T)` *cast-expression* is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type; otherwise the result is a prvalue.

In your case,

`T` is not an lvalue reference.
`T` is not an rvalue reference to function type.
`T` is not an rvalue reference to object type.

Hence, the result is a prvalue of type `T`.

If you look further into the definitions of prvalue and rvalue (Section 3.10), the result is a temporary object.

The temporary object is constructed using the **Explicit type conversion (funtional notation)**.

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)**
>
> 1 A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier* (14.6) followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* **constructs a value of the specified type** given the expression list.

Comment: The value language is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider this piece of code:

```
((T)(y)).doSomething();
```

Here *C-style* cast *(T)(y)* is applied.

Basically compiler performs *static_cast* from *T&* to *T* in this situation (look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) for details).

Now from the *cppreference.com* [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

> static_cast < new_type > ( expression )
>
> ...
>
> 1) If there is an implicit conversion sequence from expression to
>   new_type, ... then static_cast(expression) returns the
>   imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type
>   Temp(expression);

There is an implicit conversion from *T&* to *T*, so temporary is created by *static_cast*.

Comment: Generally speaking, I am not so sure about some details of my answer. So I am open for the discussion :)